# How can I use Model.NodeById(1234) in a .CS Class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, umbraco

New to Umbraco. I am using Umbraco 7 in C#.

I have created a CS class in App_Code folder.

In a Macro i am used to be able to fetch a node info (such as name etc.) buy using this code:

```
Model.NodeById(1234)
```

If i do this in the .cs class i get a compiler error, saying that I can't use "Model".

I'm pretty sure that i am missing someting at the top of my code like:

```
 using umbraco.somethingsomething
```

I'm pretty sure that this is basic for any novice Umbraco / .net user. So any help is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Include this at the top:

```
using umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory;
```

And then create a new dynamic node:

```
var item_node = new DynamicNode(1234);
```

Get some property from the node:

```
var somVariabel = item_node.GetProperty("propertyName").Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I will recommend you to use one of the new api's. DynamicNode is very old. If you want your node as a dynamic, use UmbracoHelper.

Comment: @MortenOC thx my freind, i didn't know that. I will look into your solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want, you could use the "new" ContentService

```
var cs = Services.ContentService;
var node = cs.GetById(1234)
```

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService

Or use UmbracoHelper

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var node = umbracoHelper.Content(1234);
```

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/